# SQL - Efficient versioning of DNS records

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, common-table-expression, database-administration

So far I have come up with this solution that needs further refinement (big thanks to #postgresql on freenode).

The problem I am trying to overcome is an efficient way of storing DNS records whilst maintaining some sort of history. The issue I am currently having is with the wCTE which is inserting new records and deleting old records correctly. It isn't, however, readding records. The wCTE is:

```
 WITH deltas AS (
     SELECT o, n FROM (
         SELECT id, name, domain_id, class_id, addr FROM record WHERE tld_id = $1
     ) AS o FULL OUTER JOIN record_temp n
     ON (
         o.name = n.name AND 
         o.domain_id = n.domain_id AND 
         o.class_id = n.class_id AND 
         o.addr = n.addr
     )
     WHERE (o.name, o.domain_id, o.class_id, o.addr)
     IS DISTINCT FROM (n.name, n.domain_id, n.class_id, n.addr)
 ), mark_dead AS (
     UPDATE record SET alive = FALSE 
     WHERE id IN (
         SELECT (o).id FROM deltas WHERE (o).id IS NOT NULL
     ) RETURNING *
 )
 INSERT INTO record (name, domain_id, tld_id, class_id, addr)
 SELECT (n).name, (n).domain_id, (n).tld_id, (n).class_id, (n).addr
 FROM deltas WHERE
     (n).name IS NOT NULL AND 
     (n).domain_id IS NOT NULL AND 
     (n).tld_id IS NOT NULL AND 
     (n).class_id IS NOT NULL AND
     (n).addr IS NOT NULL
 ;
```

The o result has all the old records that do not exist in record_temp, n has all the records that are new and need to be inserted. I expect I need to add another join which pulls in (an inner join?) results that exist on both tables (which if marked as dead, need to be marked as alive).

The rest of the schema for reference is:

```
  CREATE TABLE record (
        id SERIAL,
        name VARCHAR(255),
        domain_id INT,
        tld_id INT,
        class_id INT,
        addr INET,
        alive BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES domain (id) MATCH SIMPLE,
        CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (tld_id) REFERENCES tld (id) MATCH SIMPLE,
        UNIQUE(name, domain_id, class_id, addr)
  );

  CREATE TABLE record_history (
        id SERIAL,
        record_id INT,
        history_type record_history_type,
        stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (record_id) REFERENCES record (id) MATCH SIMPLE,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
  );

 CREATE TEMP TABLE record_temp (
     name VARCHAR(255),
     domain_id INT,
     tld_id INT,
     class_id INT,
     addr INET,
     UNIQUE(name, domain_id, class_id, addr)
 )
 ON COMMIT DROP;
```

record_history is populated using functions and triggers and is populating how I expect it to, below are these triggers:

```
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO record_history (record_id, history_type) VALUES (NEW.id, 'added');
        RETURN NEW;
      END;
  $$ language 'plpgsql';

  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
     BEGIN
        IF NEW.alive = OLD.alive THEN
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        IF NEW.alive THEN
            INSERT INTO record_history (record_id, history_type) VALUES (NEW.id, 'added');
        END IF;
        IF NOT NEW.alive THEN
            INSERT INTO record_history (record_id, history_type) VALUES (NEW.id, 'deleted');
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ language 'plpgsql';

    ON record FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
        add_insert_record_history();

    ON record FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
        add_update_record_history();
```

Comment: The supplied update commands are syntactically wrong.

Comment: If you want this table to serve history (or versioning) too, *at least* one of the timestamp fields should be part of the key.

Comment: If you want to be able to track all version history then you need to disallow updates for SET alive = TRUE: such an action will need an additional INSERT instead. My recommendation is to mediate all update/insert access to the table  via stored procedures so you can enforce your desired API.

Comment: I have updated my question with my progress, not sure it deserves a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have it working how I want with the following query, which I feel is incredibly unoptimized:

```
    WITH deltas AS (
        SELECT o, n FROM (
            SELECT id, name, domain_id, class_id, addr FROM record WHERE tld_id = $1
        ) AS o FULL OUTER JOIN record_temp n
        ON (
            o.name = n.name AND 
            o.domain_id = n.domain_id AND 
            o.class_id = n.class_id AND 
            o.addr = n.addr
        )
        WHERE (o.name, o.domain_id, o.class_id, o.addr)
        IS DISTINCT FROM (n.name, n.domain_id, n.class_id, n.addr)
    ), mark_dead AS (
        UPDATE record SET alive = FALSE 
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT (o).id FROM deltas WHERE (o).id IS NOT NULL
        ) RETURNING *
    ), mark_alive AS (
        UPDATE record SET alive = TRUE
        WHERE alive = FALSE AND id IN (
            SELECT id FROM (
                SELECT id, name, domain_id, class_id, addr FROM record WHERE tld_id = $1
            ) AS o INNER JOIN record_temp n
            ON (
                o.name = n.name AND 
                o.domain_id = n.domain_id AND 
                o.class_id = n.class_id AND 
                o.addr = n.addr
            )
        ) RETURNING *
    )
    INSERT INTO record (name, domain_id, tld_id, class_id, addr)
    SELECT (n).name, (n).domain_id, (n).tld_id, (n).class_id, (n).addr
    FROM deltas WHERE
        (n).name IS NOT NULL AND 
        (n).domain_id IS NOT NULL AND 
        (n).tld_id IS NOT NULL AND 
        (n).class_id IS NOT NULL AND
        (n).addr IS NOT NULL
    ;
```